# Captcha MVC con IP

Tags: html, c#, mvc, captcha

Tengo una consulta, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar un **CAPTCHA** en `MVC` según la **IP**? 
Es decir, supongamos que tengo una **VPN** con **IPs** (1.1.1.1/2.2.2.2/etc). Quiero que si la persona que ingresa a la página posee una **IP** de la **VPN** pueda acceder a la página siguiente. Pero, si la **IP** no pertenece a la **VPN** quiero que cada tres **IPs** diferentes muestre un **CAPTCHA**. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? 
Me basé en un ejemplo de Google para hacer el **CAPTCHA**:

**Head:**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

**Body:**

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Pdf", "Home")">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="la-clave-sitio"></div>
                <label for="solicitud">Solicitud: </label>
                <input type="text" id="solicitud" minlength="5" maxlength="7" name="solicitud" placeholder="Solicitud..." required
                       title="Sólo letras y números. Cantidad mínima de caracteres: 5. Cantidad máxima de caracteres: 7"
                       onkeypress="return soloLetrasYnumeros(event)">
                <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
            </form>
```

¿Alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución sería crear un `Array` de `String` que contenga las IP y luego preguntar si estan o no incluídas para mostrar el **Captcha**

```
var ladoA = new[]
            {
                "1.1.1.0",
                "1.1.1.1",
                "1.1.1.2",
                "1.1.1.3",
                "1.1.1.4",
                "1.1.1.5"
            };
            string ip = IP();
            if (ip != ladoA)
            {
                ViewBag.Mensaje = "No es válido";
            }
            else 
            { 
               ViewBag.Mensaje="Ip Válida";
            }
            return View();
        }

        public string IP() 
        {
            string host = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPAddress[] ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);
            return ip[1].ToString();
        }
```